# Scrapy - encoding csv file utf-8

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I looked all over this website, I did the same on google but I found nothing about exporting the data in a csv file encoding utf-8.

I need to encode my file because I have some french characters (like É).
I use CsvItemExporter, which is normally already encode in utf-8 but it doesn't give me the correct characters. Instead of these char, I only have some weird things like \A4ybzkzv and I don't know how to have the correct ones.

I hope I have been clear enough!! Thank you for your help...

Here is my pipelines.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

# Define your output file.
class FnacPipeline(CsvItemExporter):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        f = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'w').close()
        file = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'w')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

With this pipeline, I have an error and not the right characters : `TypeError: must be str, not bytes` and when I change `file = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'w')` to `file = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'wb')`, I have no more error but not the right char...

The output I have :
`France mÃ©tropolitaine`

The output I want :
`France métropolitaine`

Comment: Quick question, why aren't you using in-built scrapy exporters? You can simply export your results with `-o` flag: `scrapy crawl myspider -o results.csv` or you can also set [some settings to do that](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html).

Comment: @Granitosaurus Saying that, I think some settings or customization is the exact thing he is doing. :)

Comment: As I have many projects, with sometimes many spiders in the same project, I want to create a csv file by spider... And I run my spiders automatically through an executable file. So I don't want to re-write my exe file each time I want to run a spider :)

Comment: And I'm not sure I understand your comment because I already use an in-built scrapy exporter, isn't it? I'm new in scrapy so forgive me if I'm wrong...

Comment: And finally, does that command (`scrapy crawl myspider -o results.csv`) will change anything on my encoding problem?

Comment: You can use custom settings in per spider with spider class variable `custom_settings`, see [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=custom_settings#settings-per-spider). Other than that `-o` should deal with all of the encoding issues, as by default it should output utf8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to open a **text** file for writing using utf-8 encoding with Python 3 is as follow:

```
fd = open(path, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
fd.write("Unicode string")
```

But your `CsvItemExporter` seams to do the encoding for you, so it writes binary data to your file. So the best way is to open your file in binary format:

```
fd = open(path, mode='wb')
fd.write(b"Binary string")
```

The result: "France mÃ©tropolitaine" is correct. The problem is that you don't use the right editor to read your file. You are certainly using Excel. And Excel opens CSV files using cp1252 by default on the French version. You need to import the file in order to have the possibility to choose the source encoding. Note: you won't have this problem with Libre Office.

Comment: I just opened my file as you told me (on excel, import data...) and you're right... I didn't opened it the right way... Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

So the correct answer was to save it as `utf-8` and use excel `Import` to view that property.

On the other hand, you can view it in Excel by opening it directly but the default encoding was `cp12523`.

For me, I can't just tell to my client to use the `Import` of excel, so I choose to change the encoding to `cp1252` so it didn't view correctly.

When you change the configuration in `settings.py` an set to `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` will not going to work.

What I did was change the `pipelines.py` under `spider_opened` function,

```
self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file, encoding='cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
         self.csvfile  = open(self.filename, 'wb')
         self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.csvfile, encoding='utf-8-sig')
         self.exporter.start_exporting()
```